# CSS Pre-Loader fadeout

Tags: jquery, css, fadeout

How can I get my pre loader to fade out smoothly, my code below is not working

CSS

```
.body{
     width:100%;
     height:1000px;
     overflow:hidden;
    }
    #loader{
         width:100px;
         height:100px;

         border:solid 5px blue;
         border-top:solid 5px #F69;
         border-bottom:solid 5px #F69;
         border-radius:100%;

         position:absolute;
         top:0;
         left:0;
         right:0;
         bottom:0;
         margin:auto;

         -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
         animation: spin 2s linear infinite;

        }
    @keyframes spin{
            from{ transform:rotate(0deg);  width:100px;
            height:100px;}
            to{ transform:rotate(360deg); width:100px;
            height:100px;}
        }
```

CODE

```
<body onload="myFunction()" >
   <div id="loader" style="z-index:999;">
   </div>
 </body>
```

Script

```
    function myFunction() {
        $("bloader").fadeOut(2000);
        myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script

```
$("bloader").fadeOut(2000);
```

should be

```
$("#loader").fadeOut(2000);
```